# How to transform a piece of text into a link?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I was wondering if it is possible to "transform" a piece of text into a link.

For example:

I have a Label that contains the text: "By accepting our terms and conditions you will be able to access the survey **(Read More)**"

I would like **Read More** to be a link so that it's clickable. 
Is this possible within a label (or textfield)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using UI5, consider [using available controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373872/5846045) instead of manipulating the DOM directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can capture the html inside your label and transform it.
As others comment, you can do it for a `label` but not in a text `input` field.

assuming jquery in your front end, that would be something like this...

```
let h = $('label#your-id").html();
h = h.replace('(Read More)','<a href="#">(Read More)</a>');
$('label#your-id').html(h);
```

or if you want to do it in all of your `label`s

```
$('label').each( (i,l) => {
  let h = $(l).html();
  h = h.replace('(Read More)','<a href="#">(Read More)</a>');
  $(l).html(h);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using the UI5 framework, you can make use of the available controls that support links within texts such as [`sap.m.FormattedText`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.FormattedText/preview) or [`sap.m.MessageStrip`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessageStripWithEnableFormattedText/preview) with `enableFormattedText`.

### Demo

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/FormattedText",
  "sap/m/MessageStrip",
], function(FormattedText, MessageStrip) {
  new FormattedText({
    htmlText: getFormattedText()
  }).addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMargin").placeAt("content");
  new MessageStrip({
    enableFormattedText: true,
    showIcon: true,
    text: getFormattedText(),
  }).addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMargin").placeAt("content");
  function getFormattedText() {
    return `By accepting our terms and conditions you will be able to access the survey <a href="https://example.com" target="_self">(Read More)</a>`;
  }
}));
```

```html
<script>
  window["sap-ui-config"] = {
    libs: "sap.m, sap.ui.core",
    preload: "async",
    theme: "sap_belize",
    compatVersion: "edge",
    "xx-waitForTheme": true,
    "xx-async": true,
  }
</script>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within a label but not an input field.

```
<form>
  <label for="textbox">By accepting our terms and conditions you will be able to access the survey <a href="http://www.mylink.com">(Read More)</a></label>
  <input type="text" name="textbox"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle these kind of scenarios is with [Message Strip](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MessageStrip). Just add:

```html
<MessageStrip id="idMessageStrip" enableFormattedText="true" showIcon="true" showCloseButton="true" class="sapUiMediumMarginBottom">
<link>
    <Link text="Text to be displayed as link goes here" press="handleLinkClick"/>
</link>
</MessageStrip>
```